# Marker should follow Cursor

Tags: highcharts

I couldn’t find a possibility in the highchairs docs to interpolate the marker position between 2 x-axis points. It just sticks to this points instead to the crosshair (on the y-axis).
https://i.ibb.co/n0ZWpmC/Bildschirmfoto-2019-09-02-um-10-40-00.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crosshair` with disabled `snap` property and with `label` or increase the point density.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        crosshair: {
            snap: false,
            label: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{value:.2f}'
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        stickyTracking: false,
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vh7rf3jx/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair.snap

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair.label

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.stickyTracking